# Why Mathematicas `FindRoot` can't find solution?

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving

I have a following simple code which numerically evaluates critical load for a simply supported bar (with BC at both ends $y(0)=y(l)=0$) with non-prismatic cross-section. Just for a simplification let's assume that $E=l = 1$ and $I(x) = (8x^3+1)$, where $E$ is the Young modulus, $l$ is the length of the element and $I(x)$ is the function of its moment of inertia.

```
bar[p_] := (8 x^3 + 1) y''[x] + p y[x] == 0
cond[p_] := y[1] /. NDSolve[{bar[p], y[0] == 0, y'[0] == 1}, y, {x, 0, 1}]
Plot[cond[p], {p, 0, 100}, AxesLabel -> {p, y[1]}]
```

It's graphical interpretation of shooting method which reduces boundary value problem into initial value problem.

The code gives the plot on which we can clearly see that the solution is around `p -> 17.582` but I can't understand why `FindRoot` fails.

```
FindRoot[cond[p],{p,10,20}]
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: `WhenEvent[]` might be useful here.

Comment: Use `?NumericQ`: `ClearAll[cond]; cond[p_?NumericQ] :=...`

Comment: Thanks @MichaelE2, I was't aware about that issue. Your suggestion was very helpful.